# Transition to state ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a http interceptor which has to redirect to the login page if it has a statuscode of 401.

The code is as follow:

```
responseError: function(response) {
   if (response.status === 401) {
      $window.sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
      $injector.get('$state').go('guest.login');
   }
   return response || $q.when(response);
}
```

Here I have the `guest.login` state defined:

```
.state('guest', {
   abstract: true
})

.state('guest.login', {
   templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
   url: '/login',
   controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})
```

When I the request returns a 401 error, I get a error:

`Could not resolve 'guest.login' from state '...'`

I've tried both $state.go and $state.transitionTo.

**How am I suppose to go to my login page with ui-router?**

Answer (score 1):

Every state tries to populate the ui-view of its parent state. 'guest.login' has the parent 'guest' but the 'guest' state has no ui-view. Adding it in should fix this. This is a common pitfall with ui-router abstract states. I wish we had some better errors here (any errors).

```
state('guest', {
  abstract: true,
  template: '<ui-view/>'
})
```

Read the "Remember" part of this section: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states